# Complicated condition of getting from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want get line_id from my lines_stations table:

[image: lines_stations table]

This is timetable search so I have from form station_from_id and station_to_id.

My search function is here:

```
public function search($station_from_id, $station_to_id) {
    $stations = array($station_from_id, $station_to_id);

    $this->db->from('lines_stations');
    $this->db->where_in('station_id', $stations);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    $lines_stations = $q->result();

    return $q->result();
}
```

This return me all row from lines_stations where station_id is station_from_id or station_to_id but I need get only these where order is correctly - for example:

- station_from_id = 2
- station_to_id = 1

I should  get only this:

[image]

I haven't idea how to do this.

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Codeigniter query building, but what you need to do SQL-wise is join this table with itself on conditions that first table `station_id` equals `station_from_id`, second table `station_id` equals `station_to_id` and first table `order` is less than second table `order`.

Comment: Could you show me this query in sql?

Comment: See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a7333/3). This is the general idea, you need to tweak the select to get what you want.

Comment: could you show the station table where the `station_from_id` field is located?